# moment calendar going from December 31 2020 to 1 January 2020

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a custom built calendar component using 'moment' but I am having trouble with the change in year.

When I select a date in 2021, I get this in my console log:

```json
selectedDate:  
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Jan 01 2020 10:19:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), …}
_d: Wed Jan 01 2020 10:19:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) {}
```

```js
const today = moment().startOf("day");

  getDates = month => {
    return Array.from(Array(35)).map((_, i) => {
      return month
        .clone()
        .startOf("month")
        .startOf("isoWeek")
        .add(i, "days");
    });
  };

  nextMonth = () => {
    const month = this.state.month.clone().add(1, "month");
    console.log("check month: -=-=-=-=-=-", month);

    this.setState({
      month,
      dates: this.getDates(month)
    });
  };

  prevMonth = () => {
    const month = this.state.month.clone().subtract(1, "month");s
    this.setState({
      month,
      dates: this.getDates(month)
    });
  };

  render() {
    
    console.log("calendar state, -------", this.state);
    console.log("calendar props, =======", this.props);

    return (

---
     
          {dates.map((date, i) => {
            const selected = !!this.props.selectedDates.find(selectedDate => {
              return (
                console.log("selectedDate: ", selectedDate),
                moment(selectedDate)
                  .startOf("day")
                  .isSame(date)
              );
            });

           
            return (
              <Day
                key={i}
                isDisabled={disabled}
                isGreyed={diffMonth}
                isSelected={selected}
                onClick={() => {
                  if (isShiftHeld) {
                    return this.props.onEndDateClick(date);
                  }
                  this.props.onDateClick(date);
                }}
              >
                <DayContent>{date.format("DD")}</DayContent>
              </Day>
 ----

export default Calendar;
```

It appears to be related to the `getDates` function. It is setting the days, weeks, months for the 'current' year.

How can I adapt this to understand that after December 31, the year has increased?

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue. Don't post images, post text. The console image appears to show the date progressing from 2020-12-31 to 2021-01-01, so where's the problem? The *getDates* function seems very inefficient.

Comment: it's fine until I actually select a date in 2021. Then the response I get if I console.log it is incorrect. See update above.